# Converting str to datetime makes all the values go to NaTType

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe with dates for the last two property purchases. I have subtracted one from another, labelled that column Sale Date Diff and saved to a csv file. Now, I am trying to convert the data back to datetime, but its problematic.

Here's the data

```
Area                 Sale Date Diff
10        Downtown  16553 days 00:00:00.000000000
167       Downtown     67 days 00:00:00.000000000
555   Upper Sahali   2289 days 00:00:00.000000000
987   Brockluhurst   2912 days 00:00:00.000000000
1400   North Shore   4663 days 00:00:00.000000000
```

When I first loaded the data from csv, it had a format type 'str'.
The column has some null values, so I tried the following:

```
gdf['Sale Date Diff'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['Sale Date Diff'], errors='coerce')
```

Which converted all my data to pandas.tslib.NaTType and it now looks like this:

```
0   NaT
1   NaT
2   NaT
3   NaT
4   NaT
```

What would be a way around this?
I would also want to format the column to only have days, is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure that's a column? it looks like you have 4 different columns here.  I think you might be reading in from the `csv` incorrectly.  Also either way, you don't want `datetime`, you want `timedelta`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely convinced you're reading your `csv` correctly, it looks like you are splitting things into columns that shouldn't be split up.  However, you don't want to cast to `datetime`, you want to cast to `timedelta`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Sale Date Diff'])

10     16553 days
167       67 days
555     2289 days
987     2912 days
1400    4663 days
Name: Sale Date Diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

It would be helpful in the future to remove the `errors='coerce'` line from your code, so you can better understand what went wrong.  With that change, here is the error you would have seen:

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '16553 days 00:00:00.000000000')
```

This was caused by you trying to cast a string representing a `timedelta` object, to a Timestamp.